# Javascript alert box blocks sound object

Tags: javascript, audio, alert

I have a small problem. Basically, I am trying to make an application that it will pop up a box while playing a certain sound. Here is the fault part of the code:

```
    var audio = new Audio('song.mp3');
    audio.play();
    alert(1);
```

The problem is that the audio plays after the alert box. I guess this happens because the application doesn't load the song file immediately but I have now idea how can I make it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **canplay event** occurs when the browser can start playing the specified audio/video (when it has buffered enough to begin).

So try this:

```
var audio = new Audio('song.mp3');
    audio.oncanplay  = function() {
        audio.play();
        alert("1");
    };
```